# How to avoid mysql injections using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, code-injection

How can I avoid mysql injections? This is the PHP file I have right now

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$Name = $_GET['Name'] ;

$sql = "Select * from tables where names =\"$Name\"";



try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $names = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"key":'. json_encode($names) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}


?>
```

When I put `$stmt = $dbh->query($sql); $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));` to the code it doesn't work. So how should I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read about [pdo prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Here is an example

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE names = :name");
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
```

Comment: This is very important and oft misunderstood: *just using PDO doesn't protect you from SQL injection.* Only parametrized queries like the one above do.

Comment: @skwee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602 says that only PDO prepared statements can't prevent injection. take a look at this.